# unmet dependencies error after installing squid

Tags: 12.04, error-handling, squid

I have this error message after running "sudo apt-get squid3 install" in terminal on ubuntu 12.04

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 squid3 : 

Depends: squid3-common (= 3.1.19-1ubuntu3.12.04.3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: Typically these problems can be solved by reading carefully the output of `sudo aptitude install squid3` and looking at a few different solutions (respond `n`)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
I had to download the "squid-langpack" using my browser and installed it on the ubuntu after which the "sudo apt-get install squid-common" and "sudo apt-get install squid3"

Answer (score -1):

Is this all. If so then try installing the squid3-common package manually using

```
apt-get install squid3-common
```

and then try installing squid again.

Comment: Yeah I saw this somewhere online...I would do that and provide appropriate response if it works

Comment: he following packages have unmet dependencies:
 squid3-common : Depends: squid-langpack (>= 20110214-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubabf@BFKAPROXYSRV:~$ sudo apt-get install squid-langpack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package squid-langpack is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: This is because the package squid-langpack isnt available. It would be solved once you install it manually which you did.